# Как получить температуру устройства

Tags: java, android

Как получить значение: TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE?
Предположение:

```
int temperature = Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE;
    result.setText(temperature);
```

Comment: Простите, температуру чего? Программы intellij idea?

Comment: Температуру andoid-устройства.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
temperatureSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
if(temperatureSensor != null) {
    sensorManager.registerListener(
        new SensorEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE) {
                    // Значение текущей температуры в event.values[0];
                }
            }
        },
        temperatureSensor, 
        sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL
    );
}
else {
    // Устройство не имеет термосенсора
}
```